# How do i get JSON data from a php into HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am brand new to this, so i have a few attempts which is leading to nowhere so i need some help to see if my approach is correct, if its totally wrong then i would need some pointer to see what i should be doing instead. Thanks in Advance.

I am trying to do a login form; what i am doing now is to submit the login form from HTML post the usernames variables etc to a Php, then if wrong password it echos wrong password in JSON etc. I can successfully make it login. 
But i can not get the JSON through the JavaScript. When i click submit, it runs through the php and then it echos the JSON in a new php page. But not returning the JSON to the html.  I also am using Twitter Bootstrap.

My php

```
$password1= mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$password);
$username= mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$username);

if (!$username||!$password) {
    $no="Please enter name and password";
    echo ($no);
} else {
    //log in
    $login = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM User WHERE username='$username'")or die(mysqli_error());
    if (mysqli_num_rows($login)==0){
        echo json_encode("No such user");
    } else {
        while ($login_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($login)) {
            //get database password
            $password_db = $login_row['password'];

            //encrypt form password
            $password1 = md5($password1);

            //check password
            if ($password1!=$password_db) {
                echo json_encode("Incorrect password");
            } else {
                //assign session
                $_SESSION['username']=$username;
                $_SESSION['password']=$password1;
                header  ("Location: http://------.com/Bootstraptest/account.html");
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

JavaScript

```
<script>

var myButton = document.getElementById("signin");
    var myText = document.getElementById("result");

    myButton.addEventListener('click', getServerTime, false)

    function getServerTime() {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "http://rentaid.info/Bootstraptest/tet.php";
        request.open("GET", url, true);
        request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");


 request.onload = showTime;
        request.send();
    }
    function showTime(response) {
        var time = JSON.parse(response);
        myText.textContent = ;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Look in the [JavaScript error console](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) and tell what errors you see there and which lines they point to.

Comment: Please display the error.
On another note, in the code, sometimes you `echo` a string and sometimes you `echo` a JSON string. This is wrong because `JSON.parse` will fail if it receives a string instead of a JSON string.

Comment: Ok,because it is not displaying any error, so i am not sure how to figure out the problem, it just links me to a blank php with the json echoed there.

Comment: @Clarklight, try adding `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set("display_errors", true);` at the beginning of your script to make sure errors are shown.  See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php for more details.

Comment: I have this on the first line ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);
This is what i mean http://www.rentaid.info/Bootstraptest/ if you click login and type in a random user and password, i am trying to have the JSON displayed on the same page, but it is going to a blank php at the moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `getServerTime`, you don't reference your `showTime` function.

Change it to this:

```
function getServerTime() {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "http://rentaid.info/Bootstraptest/tet.php";
    request.open("GET", url, true);
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.onload = showTime;

    request.send();
    return false;
}
function showTime(response) {
    myText.textContent = response;
    var time = JSON.parse(response);
    //myText.textContent = time;
}
```

The first line in `showTime` will help you debug in case there's a problem with your JSON format.

Answer (score 0):

That part seems broken:

function showTime(response) {
    var time = JSON.parse(response);

**myText.textContent = ;**
}

this other part seems really weird too:

$login = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM User WHERE username=**'$username'**")

Maybe I don't know what tech you're using but it seems that either you failed concatenation or you failed paramaterized query.

Tell me what you tried there?

Comment: The php parts works ok, because i can login, if i type in the right password, and when i login with a wrong password or wrong username, it echos it correctly but it echos it on a blank php page.

Comment: http://www.rentaid.info/Bootstraptest/ Here is what it is doing, when i type in random username, and password, it echos "no such user" but it goes to a blank page and echo that

Comment: Maybe i dont supposed to use Javascript to parse the JSON back to the html? Cos i am just following the example from here http://www.kirupa.com/html5/displaying_php_data_in_html.htm and it works on that site

Comment: When do you use that function?:

function showTime(response) {
    var time = JSON.parse(response);
 

 
myText.textContent = ":";
}


Is it the function supposed to write the error?

Comment: Hi yer that supposed to parse through if the JSON has an error right? I am just not so sure how does JSON is parse through from the php into Javascript then displayed in the html. Because i thought i did that, setting the url request in function getserverTime, then parsing the JSON then thats the confused part.

Comment: You are doing it right, but you're never calling the function that uses the response.
Therefore, it works as a PHP redirect when you login sucessfully but how can it work when you give a response in case of failure?

Comment: I just realized that, i just added a part  function processData(e) {


showTime(e.target.responseText);

}, Does it mean, that if the data is parsed through correctly, it wont get redirected to a PHP?

Comment: It should not redirect you. The issue is weird, I've never encountered it but if you give us more precise code or if you correct your possible mistakes, I guess it should be fine ^^

Comment: Ok, sweet thanks for the help, thats all the code i have for the Javascript at the moment, the rest are just the html code. I will try to figure it out!

Comment: I tried it again, i put function showTime(e) {
   var myText = JSON.parse(e.target.responseText);
   
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =  myText   ;
}
  it is echoing the correct JSON, but it still redirects me to a php.